# How present a UIAlert in a Skscene SWIFT

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I've looked around nobody has this answer in Swift so here it is. I get an error saying the game scene does not have a member named `presentViewController`.

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Nothing Selected",
                                      message: "You have not selected a picture.",
                               preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)    
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dang!",
                                        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
                                      handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alertController, 
                           animated: true, 
                         completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last line of code, instead of

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

try

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works for me. :)

Comment: Came from 2017 with the same issue now and managed to find the same answer that helped me over a year ago. lol thanks. Still works as of iOS 10 and Swift 3.